# Loading non-s3 data source for Sagemaker Java SDK

Tags: java, aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker

I'm setting up a lambda function that performs SageMaker inferences using the Random Cut Forest algorithm. I successfully ran the python RCF example in a jupyter notebook, but I prefer to have my lambda written in Java, and I was hoping to not use an s3 bucket in the process. I know that if my lambda was in python, then I would be able to pass in my data, convert it to a pandas dataframe, then run `rcf_inference.predict(data)` to obtain my results. But with Java, this is seemingly impossible.

I was able to make a batch transform job using the following Java code, but after examining the java aws-sdk documentation, it looks like my TransformDataSource *must* have an S3DataSource, and not any other kind of source. This is unfortunate because my lambda already has the data I need in memory, so uploading/downloading to/from an s3 bucket is unnecessary.

```
        String bucket = "test-bucket441";
        String prefix = "sagemaker/rcf-benchmarks";
        String trainedModel = "randomcutforest-2019-06-28-13-43-00-925";

        AmazonSageMaker sm = AmazonSageMakerClientBuilder.standard().build();

        TransformS3DataSource s3Source = new TransformS3DataSource()
                .withS3DataType("S3Prefix")
                .withS3Uri("s3://" + bucket + "/" + prefix);

        TransformDataSource dataSource = new TransformDataSource()
                .withS3DataSource(s3Source);

        TransformInput input = new TransformInput()
                .withContentType("text/csv")
                .withDataSource(dataSource);

        TransformOutput output = new TransformOutput()
                .withS3OutputPath("s3://" + bucket + "/" + prefix + "/output")
                .withAssembleWith("Line");

        TransformResources resources = new TransformResources()
                .withInstanceType("ml.m4.xlarge")
                .withInstanceCount(1);

        CreateTransformJobRequest jobRequest = new CreateTransformJobRequest()
                .withTransformJobName("test-job")
                .withModelName(trainedModel)
                .withTransformInput(input)
                .withTransformOutput(output)
                .withTransformResources(resources);


        sm.createTransformJob(jobRequest);
```

Does anyone know any way I can create a CreateTranformJobRequest without using an s3 bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Python code uses a SageMaker HTTPS endpoint for real-time prediction: although the SageMaker SDK is Python only, you can absolutely do the same thing with the (lower level) AWS SDK for Java.

Assuming you've already trained your model in SageMaker, you would:

- create an endpoint configuration,
- create an endpoint,
- invoke the endpoint.

The corresponding APIs are detailed in:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemaker/AmazonSageMaker.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemakerruntime/AmazonSageMakerRuntime.html